# authorindex+natbib producing incorrect page numbers

Tags: bibtex, natbib, authorindex

I am using `natbib` and `authorindex`. The [`authorindex` manual](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/athena/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/authorindex/authorindex.pdf), section 7.2.3, indicates that there is a conflict between the two packages and suggests a fix that involves creating a `natbib.cfg` file. When I do this, the author index produces incorrect page numbers. I suspect the problem is in the `natbib.cfg` file, but I am not familiar enough with that part of LaTeX to interpret the code in that file. Here is a MWE:

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[biblabels,editors,firstabbrev]{authorindex}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[7]

\citet{Ha13}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{mybib}

\section*{Author Index}

\printauthorindex

\end{document}
```

**mybib.bib**

```
@article{Ha13,
    Author = {Harris, Ford W.},
    Journal = {Factory: The Magazine of Management},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {135-136, 152},
    Title = {How Many Parts to Make at Once},
    Volume = {10},
    Year = {1913}}
```

**natbib.cfg**

```
% natbib.cfg
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{authorindex}{%
\ifNAT@numbers
\let\org@@citex\NAT@citexnum
\else
\let\org@@citex\NAT@citex
\fi
\def\@citex[#1][#2]#3{%
\typeout{indexing: [#1][#2]{#3}}%
\org@@citex[#1][#2]{#3}%
\@aicitey{#3}}%
\renewcommand\NAT@wrout[5]{%
\if@filesw{%
\let\protect\noexpand\let~\relax
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\aibibcite{#5}{#1}}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#5}{{#1}{#2}{{#3}}{{#4}}}}}%
\fi}}{}}
\endinput
```

I am compiling the document as `latex` > `bibtex` > `latex` > `authorindex` > `latex`. All of these commands are run from TeXShop, except for `authorindex`, which I run from a Terminal prompt, as `authorindex mwe`.

The reference is cited on page 2 of the document, but it shows up in the author index as page 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was using the `biblabels` option, which meant that `authorindex` was reporting "the reference label as it appears in the reference list" (according to the `authorindex` manual), rather than the page number. Under `abbrevnat` there are no reference labels, so I assume they are treated as consecutive numbers. Thus, my one reference was showing up as "1" no matter what page it was cited on. (And when I added more references, they showed up as 2, 3, 4, ...)

Removing the `biblabels` option fixed the problem.